# Configure Git Remote server with Putty For Windows Pc

Tags: windows, git, server, private, putty

right now i'm working on my school's development department.
Lately we've gotten a Ubuntu Server, I mean, the school has given us the server with Ubuntu OS.
The last week my boss said that he wanted to use Git on the server, but all our machines have Windows OS.

I've been searching a lot of information about doing this but i noticed that the information is mostly too old and obsolete.

I don't really know the exactly way to to this, i mean, i know that i need to update the server (sudo apt-get update), then install Git and assign the global user email and name, after that, get the ssh keygen but is in this point where i don't know what to do, because in some of the web tutorials they use their machines whit different OS.

Is there any proven new way to solve this problem? ->Configure with windows the private Git server and then use it with windows machines?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean setup a Git server on Windows, no need for putty.

Install:

- [Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases)
- [Gitea.io](https://gitea.io/en-US/) (very simple setup: just one exe to copy, that's it)

And you have a Git server on Windows!